# C# WinForms Vertical Alignment for TextBox, etc

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment

I'm working on a project updating their WinForms application UI to be more consistent with sizes.  TextBox and ComboBox controls have different heights by default, even with the same font.  I've been able to resize the text boxes by turning off AutoSize, but the text still hugs the top of the control, leaving a gap below.

Is there any way to center the text vertically in the control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're turning off `AutoSize` on a control, it must be a `Label`, since `TextBox` doesn't have an `AutoSize` property. The `TextAlign` property of a `Label` is of type `ContentAligment`, so you can set both horizontal and vertical alignment.

For various boring reasons, `TextBoxes` in Windows are intended to auto-adjust their heights to the font used. To control the height and vertically center the text, you can quickly create a custom `UserControl`, that you can use for replacing all your `TextBoxes` with.

On your `UserControl`, set the `BorderStyle` to `Fixed3D` and the `BackColor` to `System.Window`.  Add a `TextBox` and set its `BorderStyle` to `None`.  In the Resize event for the control, add code that makes the `TextBox` the same width as the user control's client area (accounting for the border pixels) and left-aligns it (i.e. `textBox1.Left = 0;`) and vertically centers it (e.g. `textBox1.Top = (this.Height - textBox1.Height) / 2;`).

Finally, add to the user control any `TextBox`-type properties and events you need (probably just Text and `TextChanged`, I would guess), and wire them up so that they pass through to the `TextBox` inside your control, like this:

```
public string Text
{
    get => textBox1.Text;
    set => textBox1.Text = value;
}
```

If you wanted to get super-fancy with this, you could even replace your user control's `TextAlign` property with one that is actually of type `ContentAlignment` (like the Label) and then align the inner `TextBox` to match.

This same approach works for a `ComboBox`, although it will look slightly odd.  With the `ComboBox`, you set its `FlatStyle` property to Flat - otherwise you deal with it the same as a `TextBox`.  It will look odd because the drop-down arrow box won't be quite at the top and bottom of the panel.

Comment: Just as an FYI, there is in fact an AutoSize property on TextBoxes.  It just won't show up in the property sheet or auto-complete due to some Attribute decorations.  But myTextBox.AutoSize = false; will compile, and putting that in the constructor of an inherited control will result in a resizable text box.

Comment: Noted. It's been years since I stopped trying to make Windows controls look different than the standard, so I'm a bit rusty. It's interesting that the Intellisense says "This property is not relevant for this class", even though it obviously *is* (setting it to false does indeed make the height adjustable).

Comment: I guess the easier answer is: switch to WPF. Everything has a VerticalContentAlignment and a HorizontalContentAlignment property.

Comment: I think that's precisely why they hid the property -- adjusting height is pointless if you can't adjust the alignment.
I'm trying out your solution now to see if it'll work for us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a Win32-API, message-hooking way of vertically aligning a text box, but I can't find it. I think the user control way would be less work, ultimately, and you'd have greater control over the final output.

Comment: TextBox.AutoSzie is exist but Visual studio intellise hide this.

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty `Control` and include your `TextBox` as a child. Then when the parent `Control` or the `TextBox`, resize realign your `TextBox` control in the middle vertically.

Remove the borders, make the background the same color as the parent (default). Override the font to set the `TextBox` font and I think you have will have a vertically aligned `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution is to use a `Datagridview` with 1 column, 1 row, column and row headers not visible and do `DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = MiddleLeft`.

And disable adding/deleting of rows and you have a textbox that perfectly aligns the text.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `TableLayoutPanel` solution to provide vertical alignment? You can then adjust the height as you wish, dynamically through events, OR by using a fixed value, OR with the `TableLayoutPanel`'s **row AutoSize** feature.

Just add a `TableLayoutPanel` to contain the `TextBox`. This `TableLayoutContainer` has 1 column and 3 rows.  The `TextBox` must be placed in the second row. The first and the last rows are set to 50% height (they actually use only the "remaining height"). After you placed the `TextBox` in the second row, this row can then be set to an absolute value of your choice or to Auto-size.

The `TableLayoutPanel` has its own control of width and height. But if you are placing this `TableLayoutPanel` inside a cell of another `TableLayoutPanel`, just remember to set the property Auto-size of your new `TableLayoutPanel` to true, so it can adjust itself to the size of the cell.

In general, `TableLayoutPanels` are of great help for your design, I definitely recommend using them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the idea Boeryepes share, to use a Datagridview like a TextBox, i created this. Add a Datagridview, set location and size, and then:

```
    private void SetupTextBoxDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(column);
        //dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "C" + dataGridView.Name;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        dataGridView.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Window;
        dataGridView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;   //FixedSingle
        dataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single;
        dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;   //Window Cell color when in focus or selected
        dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
        dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Window;   //Window Cell color when not in focus or selected
        dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
        dataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
        dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;

        dataGridView.Rows.Add("");

        dataGridView.CellBeginEdit += DataGridView_CellBeginEdit;
        dataGridView.CellEndEdit += DataGridView_CellEndEdit;
        //dataGridView.MouseEnter += DataGridView_MouseEnter;
    }
    private void DataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView control = sender as DataGridView;
        control.GridColor = SystemColors.Highlight;   //Border Color - SystemColors.ControlDark
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)control.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value))
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
        }
    }
    private void DataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView control = sender as DataGridView;
        control.GridColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;   //Border Color - SystemColors.ControlDark
    }
    //Begin Edit Mode automatically when mouse enter the cell
    private void DataGridView_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView control = sender as DataGridView;
        DataGridViewCell cell = control[control.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, control.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsInEditMode && !cell.ReadOnly)
        {
            control.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
```

How to use:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetupTextBoxDataGridView(dataGridView2);
    }
```

How to use:

```
        //Get text
        txtNew.Text = (string)dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value;
        //Add text
        dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value = "Hello";
        dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Hello";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply adjust padding - vertical higher. Property in category layout.

Comment: No, you can't. The TextBox control doesn't have a Padding property.