# Aligning text of TextBox in c# Right and Bottom

Tags: c#, user-interface, textbox

I'm making a calculator in c#. I know the logic required to make a calculator. But the problem I'm facing is with the UI, I want to make the text in my TextBox Right and Bottom, while there is TextAlign property which makes the text in the TextBox align to right, I'm having trouble making it align to the bottom?.I really tried finding an answer.

[image]

but I want something like this

[image]

Also how to move the text in the textbox slightly upper when I press any operator?

Comment: Maybe that might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/712d4df4-64e4-4748-8bff-6b9ed0db46fb/textbox-text-vertical-alignment?forum=winforms

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653153/c-sharp-winforms-vertical-alignment-for-textbox-etc

Comment: May be the question is stupid but atleast answer it downvoter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fact that you only use the `TextBox` for displaying the user input, a `Label` will allow for better use of what you want.

The `Label` supports a wider use of `TextAlign` so you could use

```
Label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
```

If you want to create multiple lines inside the label, you can use `Environment.NewLine` to achieve that for example. But a `StringBuilder` and using `AppendLine` will probably work too.

If you really need to use a `TextBox` to achieve your needs, your best option would probably be to write a custom `TextBox` which supports your wanted text align.

Comment: Was it a dumb question?

Comment: @dividedbyzero I don't believe there is such thing as a question, only dumb answers. The reason why people (most likely) downvoted it, is because it's sort of an [XY-Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . But in general I personally don't think it's a dumb question.

Comment: @dividedbyzero [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is an explanation of how reputation / points work on SO. You'll get the points back if the downvoters revoke their downvote, but besides that there are lot of other ways to gain rep.

Comment: Thanks friend your answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Think this is possible with a `RichTextBox` but it would be a long work around. I would suggest using a `Label`. To align the text to the bottom right in a label you can use:

```
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
```

To change the look of the `Label` you can use:

```
label.BackColor = Color.White;
label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

To change the label from looking like a single line:

```
label.AutoSize = false;
label.Size = new Size(100,100)
```