# How to show text at the center of the TextBox in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the multiline `TextBox` control in Windows Forms application and I want to show some text at the center of the `TextBox` area (both horizontally and vertically). How can I achieve such behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not possible, most readily obvious from the missing TextAlign property.  You'll have to use a RichTextBox, SelectionAlignment property in your code.

Answer (score 7):

Set the textAlign property to center in the properties editor. It will align text in center from horizontally.

Comment: Yep, but what about the vertical alignment?

Answer (score 4):

for horizontal alignment you can use

```
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

> For various boring reasons, TextBoxes in windows are intended to auto-adjust their heights to the font used. To control the heights and vertically center the text, you can quickly create a custom UserControl that you can replace all your textboxes with.

please refer this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653360/2967572

Comment: Yep, but what about the vertical alignment?

Comment: is the textbox multiline @FrozenHeart

Comment: @FrozenHeart : please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2653360/2967572

Answer (score 2):

What you **can** do is almost as good as centering the text vertically in the TextBox:

Just put the TextBox into a TableLayoutPanel with only one single cell. Then disable the border of the TextBox and enable the border of the TableLayoutPanel, and set its background color to Window (i.e. the same as the now borderless textbox, so you can't distinguish the TextBox from the surrounding TableLayoutPanel). Finally, in order to center the TextBox vertically inside the table cell, set the anchors of the TextBox to Left+Right, so it will fill the table cell to the borders.

Note: I have forgotten to set horizontal centering for my screenshot (so as to satisfy your question), but that is trivial of course.

```
textBox1.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles)((AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right)));
textBox1.BorderStyle = 0;

tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox1, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to just vertically align the text in a textbox, you can use **VerticalContentAlignment="Center"**

Ex.:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt_box" Text="tralala" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" Height="25"/>
```

Comment: VerticalContentAlignment property is not available in Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the idea Boeryepes share https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862429/8458887, to use a Datagridview like a TextBox, i created this. Add a Datagridview, set location and size, and then:

```
private void SetupTextBoxDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(column);
    //dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "C" + dataGridView.Name;
    dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
    dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
    dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

    dataGridView.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Window;
    dataGridView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;   //FixedSingle
    dataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single;
    dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;   //Window Cell color when in focus or selected
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Window;   //Window Cell color when not in focus or selected
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    dataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
    dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;

    dataGridView.Rows.Add("");

    dataGridView.CellBeginEdit += DataGridView_CellBeginEdit;
    dataGridView.CellEndEdit += DataGridView_CellEndEdit;
    //dataGridView.MouseEnter += DataGridView_MouseEnter;
}
private void DataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView control = sender as DataGridView;
    control.GridColor = SystemColors.Highlight;   //Border Color - SystemColors.ControlDark
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)control.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value))
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
    }
}
private void DataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView control = sender as DataGridView;
    control.GridColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;   //Border Color - SystemColors.ControlDark
}
//Begin Edit Mode automatically when mouse enter the cell
private void DataGridView_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView control = sender as DataGridView;
    DataGridViewCell cell = control[control.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, control.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
    if (cell != null && !cell.IsInEditMode && !cell.ReadOnly)
    {
        control.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SetupTextBoxDataGridView(dataGridView2);
}
```

How to use:

```
    //Get text
    txtNew.Text = (string)dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value;
    //Add text
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value = "Hello";
    dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Hello";
```