# Align the Text box's text to center

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to set the `textbox` text to align at the center while using auto size property to false.I tried with Text align property, but it does't work.Here is my code.

```
 textBox1.AutoSize = false;
 textBox1.Size = new Size(100,35);
 textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Below is a screen sample :

[image]

I want the result to be as show in figure.

[image]

Comment: I need the text to be aligned at the center(Vertical)

Comment: Huh? Vertical alignment without multiline??? what is that supposed to mean?? But no you can't align vertically with or without multiline. Without it can't even set the height..

Comment: Yes,Is it possible to do ??

Comment: for winforms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653153/c-sharp-winforms-vertical-alignment-for-textbox-etc

Comment: want the same for multiline or single line?

Comment: @utility:For single line

Answer (score 7):

TextBox is one of the grand-daddy controls in the toolbox.  Goes back all the way to 1987 and Windows version 2.0.  Back when it was still a 16-bit real-mode operating system and had to run in 640 kilobytes of memory.  It is also notorious for breaking the rules, painting itself without using WM_PAINT.  The kind of thing Microsoft had to do to get acceptable perf from a 386SUX processor.  The dearth of memory was a major reason to cut down on its features.

They did not do much to improve the control, although it certainly looks a heckofalot better than it did 28 years ago.  Changing it behavior is very risky, TextBox is a major app-compat nightmare with 28 years of programmers trying to hack it to do more.

But there is no way to hack it to look the way you want it, it always renders the text top-aligned.  You must have noticed the fight that it put up to stop you from writing that code.  It is also very, very wrong code, hard-coding the size produces very undesirable accidents when it runs on a high DPI machine, displaying text with the descenders sheared-off.  AutoSize should always be set to True for a single-line TextBox to prevent such accidents.

You can otherwise emulate it pretty easily, just embed it in a panel that is as tall as you want it and set its BorderStyle property to None.  Use its Resize event to center it in the panel.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is about vertical arrangement and also for single mode there is a method but it would be working around with panels.

Place textbox inside a panel with paddings there you go :

[image]