# How to set the vertical alignment for the WindowsForms TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-alignment

In WPF it has the default support for the vertical alignment for the TextBox control. but in Windows Forms there is no way to set the vertical alignment of the TextBox control.

In My case, I have using the multi-line text box and the text is need to be displayed on the bottom of the TextBox and it need to be maintain the alignment while typing on it.

I have tried to get the line count of the entered text and try to calculate the bounds of the text box based on the length of the text. but the line count is not get properly when editing the text with word wrap.

[image]

Can any one help me on this to maintain the vertical alignment of the TextBox while editing?

I have tried to change the location of the textbox using the suggestion given in that thread. when editing the text. When I try to edit the text the bounds is not updated properly and some part of the text is hidden in the text box. I have calculated the bounds based on the font size and text width.

```
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(TextBoxText, this.textBoxControl.Font);
int textBoxTop = this.textBoxControl.Bounds.Top;
int nol = (textSize.Width > this.textBoxControl.Width) ? ((textSize.Width) / this.textBoxControl.Width) + 1 : 1;
{
    if (nol > n)
    {
        n = nol;
        rect1 = this.textBoxControl.Bounds;
        if (top + (height - nol * textSize.Height) > top)
        {
            rect1.Y = top + (height - nol * textSize.Height);
            rect1.Height = nol * textSize.Height;
            this.textBoxControl.Bounds = rect1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBoxControl.Bounds = rect1;
        }
    }
    else if (nol < n)
    {
        n = nol;
        rect1 = this.textBoxControl.Bounds;
        if (rect1.Y + nol * textSize.Height < top + height)
        {
            rect1.Y += textSize.Height - this.textBoxControl.Margin.Top;
            rect1.Height -= textSize.Height;
            //this.textBoxControl.Bounds = rect1;
        }
        if (nol == 1)
        {
            rect1.Y = top + height - textSize.Height;
            rect1.Height = textSize.Height;
            //this.textBoxControl.Bounds = rect1;
            }
            this.textBoxControl.Bounds = rect1;
    }
}
```

Its working fine while editing the text, but in some cases the `nol` Line count is calculated wrongly. How can I get the actual line count of the textbox including the wrapped lines.?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653153/c-sharp-winforms-vertical-alignment-for-textbox-etc

Comment: I have tried to change the location of the textbox using the suggestion given in that thread. when editing the text.

Comment: You can host TextBox from WPF in the WinForms.

Comment: Do some form of calculation to alter the vertical alignment using .Top e.g. textBox1.Top = (this.Height - textBox1.Height) / 2;) centre aligns or how about using a label? Which has a vertical align and doesn't have the textbox's realign rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a control that has a `TextBox` docked to the bottom of a panel that looks kinda like a `TextBox`:

```
// Make sure you have this.
    using System.Linq;

public class BottomAlignTextBox : Panel
{
    public BottomAlignTextBox()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.BorderStyle = (Application.RenderWithVisualStyles) ? BorderStyle.FixedSingle : BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
        this.Padding = new Padding(5, 0, 4, 2);

        bottomAlignTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        bottomAlignTextBox.Multiline = true;
        bottomAlignTextBox.WordWrap = true;
        bottomAlignTextBox.AcceptsReturn = true;
        bottomAlignTextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        bottomAlignTextBox.Height = 20;

        bottomAlignTextBox.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            if (bottomAlignTextBox.Height < this.Height - 20)
            {
                if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(bottomAlignTextBox.Text, bottomAlignTextBox.Font).Width > bottomAlignTextBox.Width + 6)
                {
                    string longestLine = bottomAlignTextBox.Lines.OrderByDescending(s => TextRenderer.MeasureText(s, bottomAlignTextBox.Font).Width).First();
                    bottomAlignTextBox.Text = bottomAlignTextBox.Text.Replace(longestLine, longestLine.Substring(0, longestLine.Length - 1) + Environment.NewLine + longestLine[longestLine.Length - 1]); 
                    bottomAlignTextBox.Height += 19;
                    bottomAlignTextBox.SelectionStart = bottomAlignTextBox.Text.Length + 2;
                    bottomAlignTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                }
            }
        };

        this.Controls.Add(bottomAlignTextBox);
        this.Click += delegate { bottomAlignTextBox.Focus(); };
    }

    public new string Text
    {
        get { return bottomAlignTextBox.Text; }
        set { bottomAlignTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    private TextBox bottomAlignTextBox = new TextBox();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i have tryout this but the height is calculated wrongly when i entered the text.

I have lagged in one point, where i cannot get the actual lines displayed in the textbox. once i get the proper line count i can easily calculate the height of the textbox using the code like `LineCount * FontHeight`. 

Is there any option to get those lines count..?

Comment: @Adhi I modified it now, and it moves last character of the longest line to a newline.

Comment: Hi @Shad0wk, 
Thanks for sample, i can able type the text continuously by modifying the selection start as the end of the line.  
`bottomAlignTextBox.SelectionStart = bottomAlignTextBox.Text.Length;
bottomAlignTextBox.Height += bottomAlignTextBox.Font.Height;
`


Its working fine now, but i need one more thing to be done on this. when i delete or backspace the characters from the text box, I need to reduce the row height according to the line count. how can i achieve this.

Comment: Create a int called `height` and compare it with the `Textbox.Lines.Length` to find if the height needs to be decreased. *I would update the answer but I am busy with a project.*

Comment: Hi Shad0wk,
Thanks for your concern now i can able to increase or decrease the textbox height based on the length of the lines. Now i facing one more trouble while enters to the edit mode. how can we calculate the line count of the already assigned text. 

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ahi, Maybe use a LINQ `List<T>`, or create another `TextBox` that's private, but don't add it to any control, just leave it. In the `bottomAlignTextBox.TextChanged` event make it add charcters to either the `List` or `TextBox`. Then you can manage the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is entirely possible, but I think you can wrap the control with a Panel control or some sort and Dock it to the bottom of the wrapping Panel control? If the size needs to be dynamic, playing around the Anchor properties should work as well.

Comment: Good idea! Will be even better if you show the code.

Comment: You don't really need code for this actually? You can set the Dock position of your textbox or RTB (whatever you are using) to "Bottom", set the background color of the panel same as textbox and you should be done actually... `Only if` I am getting what you are asking right.